# Tensor preserves monomorphisms

Tags: tensor-products

I am self learning simplicial homology, currently reading [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-7236-1). There, it is stated in Lemma II.5.6 (pp. 95) that:

> If $i:A\to A^\prime$ is a monomorphism of abelian groups and $G$ is a locally free abelian group, then $i\otimes id_G:A\otimes G\to A^\prime\otimes G$ is a monomorphism.

"Locally free" means that every finitely generated subgroup of $G$ is free. However I don't see why that Lemma is true even for elementary tensors. Could someone please provide a hint?  (I would not want a full proof).

Comment: For abelian groups locally free is equivalent to torsion-free is equivalent to flat as a module. Tensoring with a flat module preserves finite limits; now use the fact that a monomorphism is a map with trivial kernel.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand what you mean by "limits". I'm not well versed in the theory of modules...

Comment: In any case all you need here is that tensoring with a flat module preserves kernels. Is that something you're happy with?

Comment: I can work with that. Thank you for the help!